# Magento - getting the wrong number of the method count()

Tags: magento

Hi
I have assign 12 product to category Phone(id=12), and

> {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="12" template="catalog/product/list2.phtml"}}

in a CMS page, I have placed

> <?php 
>   $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
>   echo $_productCollection->count()
>   ?>

to list2.phtml

Why it get 9 instead of 12?

I set "Products per Page on Grid Default Value=9" in backend, is this affecting the result above, and how to fix it?

Thanks you

Comment: set a breakpoint in the _getProductCollection() method of the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List and debug using for instance xdebug with PDT . Note that it is VERY hard to do anything on Magento without a proper debugging environment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sorry that Magento API is bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of...

```
echo $_productCollection->count()
```

...try this method:

```
echo $_productCollection->getSize()
```

Internally `getSize()` uses `getSelectCountSql()` which takes the original select statement, strips off page limitations and queries the database directly. So it returns the correct answer even after the shorter, paginated, list has been loaded. Whereas `count()` returns the actual number of items in the loaded list.

Comment: just to add to @clockworkgeek - the reason why the number of items in the loaded list is not the full collection size is due to the collection being paginated.  By default, Magento will use the settings in your admin for pagination (9 per page is the default).

Comment: I also found it useful to use count($collection->getData()) for one of my recent Magento modifications.  It seems to be faster than some alternatives, though I think getSize() may do the exact same thing.

Comment: @adpro that method will give the wrong number when the results are paginated, as in the original question.  `getSize()` works in a different way and will work faster for large collections.  By calling `getData()` you will skip a few parts of the normal loading, which is slightly faster than `count()`, but also means you could be missing out on some important processing.  Please do not advise people to use that hack.